# Can't friend a class that virtual inherits from it in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to make it so that only one class, `Der`, can subclass a `Base` class. So I made the constructor of `Base` private, and added `Der` as a friend of `Base`:

```
struct Base {
 template<class T>
 friend struct Der;
 private:
  Base() = default;
};

template<class T>
struct Der : Base {};
```

This works great.

However another struct, `DerDer`, inherits from `Der`, multiple times with different template arguments.

```
struct DerDer : Der<int>, Der<char> {};
```

This is a problem because now there are two `Base` in the hierarchy, so the solution is to make `Der` virtually inherit from `Base`:

```
template<class T>
struct Der : virtual Base {};
```

This now breaks, I believe if a class is virtually inherited then the most derived class is responsible for calling the constructor (not really sure why). Which is a problem because `DerDer` is not a friend of Base and so therefore can not access it's constructor.

How can I fix this?

(It seems like it's an implementation detail that virtual inheritance makes the most derived class call the constructor, and so friending should respect that it's otherwise correct to do this and this is a kind of a bug in the compiler (or standard))

Comment: No, it's **not** an implementation detail that the most derived class calls the constructor of `Base`. I believe it is specified in the standard. Coming to your problem, the easiest work around is to make `Base::Base()` a `public` member function.

Comment: Another option would be to use composition. See this faq for the confirmation it is the standard and why it is so: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-ctors

Comment: @RSahu, I know it's in the standard,thats why I said it "seems like", as in it's only this way out of necessity (for reasons I don't understand yet). given that the most derived class calling the base's constructor is an exception to the norm, it seems reasonable that a parallel exception be made that allows the most derived class to be able to call a private constructor of a virtually inherited class. (it wouldn't be a uniform rule, but it would maen uniform behavior)

Comment: @Jonathan. Just think about it. If you inherited from two classes both inheriting from Base virtually. And you also want to delegate the call of the Base's constructor to either of them. Which one would you pick? And how could you be sure it is called only once (the reason to use virtual inheritane) in such a case since they can have their own hierarchy with yet another class inheriting from Base in them, also virtually?

Comment: @Resurrection, thanks that finally makes the penny drop :) Is there a reason in the standard why friendship doesn't work this way? It seems somewhat of an oversight.

Comment: @Jonathan. Friendship doesn't work that way in general. Just because some entity is friends with a parent class, doesn't mean it should be allowed to touch the privates of a child class...

Comment: @StoryTeller isn't that exactly how friendship works, if a class is friends with another class (parent or not), it means that class can touch it's privates? (I think I've misunderstood)

Comment: I'm saying this should be allowed, because Base's constructor would get called anyway, virtual inheritance just stops it being called multiple times, so it's not a matter of access, something being able to call something that previously wasn't allowed to be called.

Comment: @Jonathan. You have misunderstood because friendship is NOT ever inherited.

Comment: @Resurrection, I'm well aware that friendship is not inherited and completely understand why it isn't. But base constructors are not ever called before derived constructors except here with constructors of virtually inherited classes. So there should be a similar "except here with constructors of virtually inherited classes" for friendship.

Comment: @Jonathan. As I understand it the reason why is that by making the inheritance virtual the Base is no longer the base class of Der but instead is designated to be virtual base class (called once) of the most derived class. It is because in the mentioned scenario of deriving from two classes both derived from Base those two classes have no base object (it was only virtual inheritance) so they are not responsible for creating or destroying it - instead the most derived class is responsible for that.

Comment: @Resurrection, yup I understand virtual inheritance now. Just don't understand why friendship interacts with virtual inheritance the way it does (or rather doesn't)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a private nested struct to control permission to construct a `Base`.

```
struct Base {
    template<class T>
    friend struct Der;
private:
    struct Permission {};
public:
    Base(Permission) {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <class T>
struct Der : public virtual Base {
protected:
    using Permission = Base::Permission;
public:
    Der() : Base(Permission{}) {}
};

struct DerDer : Der<int>, Der<char> {
    DerDer() : Base(Der<int>::Permission{}) {}
};
```

Now writing constructors is a little awkward, but the only way to construct a `Base` is to be or inherit `Der<T>` for some `T`.

Comment: I'd leave the c'tor protected as well, but **+1** on the the tag dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

The simplest solution is to make `Base::Base()` a `public` member function.

Comment: If I do this then it would allow another class other than `Der` to inherit from `Base`?

Comment: @Jonathan. yes it would

Comment: that is what I was trying to avoid